# passing json data to a custom object - android

Tags: android, json

I'm having trouble with my application. I'm trying  to pass json data from my database in a custom class in android, and then display this in a list. When i run my app nothing happens, no errors, no list displayed. if anyone can help i would be very grateful!! :)

All the network stuff is done in async, and im trying to return the an array of objects so i suspect that this could be the problem is here or else when i am converting the string from the httphandler class into a JSONArray.

this is my main activity

```
package com.example.test1;



import java.util.ArrayList; 
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class clubpage extends Activity {

class Programme {

    public String name;
    public String event;
    public String price;

}

String clubphp = "http://10.0.2.2/corkgaa/Nemo.php";
String progString;
ArrayList<Programme> Programmedata = new ArrayList<Programme>();
ListView clublistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.clubpage);

    new Dbhandler().execute(clubphp);   

    ArrayAdapter<Programme> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Programme>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Programmedata);

    clublistview.setAdapter(adapter);


}   

public class Dbhandler extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Programme>> {

    protected ArrayList<Programme> doInBackground(String... arg0) {

ArrayList<Programme> arraydata = new ArrayList<Programme>();        
progString = httphandler.HttpGetExec(clubphp);

try{ 

    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(progString);
    JSONObject json_data=null; 

    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 

        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i); 
        Programme Progresult = new Programme();

        Progresult.name = json_data.getString("Name");
        Progresult.event = json_data.getString("Event");
        Progresult.price = json_data.getString("Price");

        arraydata.add(Progresult);

        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e1){ 

        }
    catch (ParseException e1) { 
        e1.printStackTrace();
        }
return arraydata;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Programme> result) {

    Programmedata = result;
    }

}




@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

httphandler class here:

```
package com.example.test1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient; 
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.util.Log;

public class httphandler {

//Main Dev setup

public static String HttpGetExec (String URI) {


    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String result = "no response"; 
                InputStream is = null; 
                StringBuilder sb = null;


                //http post 
                try{ 
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/corkgaa/Nemo.php"); 
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
                    is = entity.getContent(); 
                    }
                catch(Exception e){ 
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString()); 
                    }

                //convert response to string 
                try{ 
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8); 
                    sb = new StringBuilder(); 
                    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n"); 
                    String line="0"; 
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                        } 
                    is.close(); 
                    result=sb.toString(); 
                    }
                catch(Exception e){ 
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString()); 
                    }

                return result;

                //aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(clubpage.this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.title, result);
                //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.listrow, R.id.title, result);
                //listview.setAdapter(aa);

}
```

}

Comment: Do you see any of the errors (http errors) you have logged in your Logcat output

Comment: network should be accessed [asyncronously](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html#AsyncTask)

Comment: Is the fact that the httphandler class is not in async my problem? even though if it is not in the main class........ so putting all the http code in my http handler class into the async task on the main thread?

Comment: use Gson, it's way better, just take it and do a Gson().fromJson(yourjson, ClassToParse.class);

Answer (score 1):

Move this line to your `onCreate` after `setContentView`

```
clublistview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
```

And move the following lines to onPostExecute in your async task:

```
ArrayAdapter<Programme> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Programme>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Programmedata);

clublistview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

While your async task is executing, consider showing some kind of progress indicator.